# How do you identify a set of 2 or 3 digits within text? postgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-matching

I would like to find instances where there are 2 or 3 digits in the "description".

The table is like

```
id | description 
--- ------------
 1 | This is 40cm long. 
 2 | The dog is black.
```

I think that this should be a simple query and would appreciate any help.

I have tried

```
SELECT id, description
FROM table
WHERE description LIKE '%[0-9]%' or description LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]%'
```

Which returns no result though I think it should return

```
id | description 
--- ------------
 1 | This is 40cm long.
```

Thank you

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't support regular expressions in SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Postgres, use regular expressions.  This matches 1 or two digits (as in the code):

```
WHERE description ~ '[0-9]{1,2}'
```

This matches 2 or 3 (as in the description):

```
WHERE description ~ '[0-9]{2,3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing LIKE with regular expressions. You can go with the regular expression route, or look at the SQL standard SIMILAR TO:

```
WHERE description SIMILAR TO '%[0-9]{2,3}%'
```

Should get you descriptions with 2 or 3 digits

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html